# Anroid pjsua2 sample sip app cannot regsiter?

Tags: pjsip, pjsua2

I have just started playing around with pjsua2 sample android app. But i am not able to create a successful sip registration and couldnt understand userinterface properly as well. Do not know where to add caller and calle details as well. Any help would be highly appreciated . In the java file for sip implementation i see around 100 java file. what are those , are those all implementation of sip .  i have attached two image below .

[image: Are those all java sip implementation file]

[image: can any one tell me where i have to enter sip registration details and where calle number]

I would highly appreciate if any one could explain me where i have to enter calle number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should enter registration details as below

```
 ID : sip:150@123.12.xxx.123:5060
    Registrar : sip:123.12.xxx.123:5060
    Proxy : sip:123.12.xxx.123:5060
    Username : 150
    Password : 111111

And add calle details inside plus sign with 
sip:123.12.xxx.123  as well
```

From the best of understanding all those 100 files are java interfaces and classes  which you can always extend or implement  in your program. eg to create Account you can extend Account.java (which is one of those 100 java interfaces or classes )
App Folder  is where the call implementation has been written in java .

> Correct me if i am wrong